# Как сделать альтернативную ссылку в Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как сделать ссылку для новостей из sitename.com/news/1 в sitename.com/news/hello-world, если альтернативный (он же и основной) будет браться из бд. Куда копать на эту тему?

Answer (score 0):

В настройка маршрутизации (файл application/config/routes.php) указать маршрут:

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = '[controller]/[method]/$1';
```

Затем методе контроллера, который будет обрабатывать эту ссылку, проверить название статьи ("hello-world"), найти ее в БД и вывести.